# Javascript stops working after this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this code for a cmd console-like typing effect. The code itself works fine but any code I place after it doesn't work. I've been trying to figure it out for a while now and I'm pretty stuck.

Here's a JSFiddle of the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/GWj4b/

```
/**
 * CONSOLE
 */

setInterval(cursorBlink, 500);
function cursorBlink() {
    if($('#cursor').css('visibility') == 'hidden'){
        $('#cursor').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
    } else {
        $('#cursor').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
    }
}

var text = $('#type').html();
var text = text.replace(/<br>/g, '_');

$('#type').html('');

$.each(text.split(''), function(i, letter) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(letter == '_'){
            $('#type').html($('#type').html() + '<br />');
        } else {
            $('#type').html($('#type').html() + letter);
        }
    }, 100 * i);
});
```

Comment: which debuging methods have you tried so far?

Comment: Time to learn how the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) works.

Comment: First: for debugging use `console.log()` - and have a console open of course - rather than `alert()`. Sometimes you want the effect that code execution stops, but in most cases it's more a hindrance than a benefit, because you can do this better with breakpoints. Also, the console formats complex data (objects, arrays) much better.

Comment: ...and you have two `var text = ...` statements. Won't lead to errors but is wrong, remove the second `var` in front of the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the console log you see: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

text is not defined when you call replace on it because the element you're looking for doesn't exist.

You can test to see if it exists like this

```
if(text) {
  text.replace(/<br>/g, '_');
}
```

Javascript will stop execution if it hits a runtime error like this.

Consider learning more about debugging this type of issue with Chrome's [dev tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or an equivalent in your browser.  Once you look to see the error, its pretty clear what line is causing the issue.

Incidentally, after adding the elements that you are trying to reference, the code executes through.  If they might not exist though, you need to do the checking in code, and its a good habit regardless.

http://jsfiddle.net/GWj4b/1/

Comment: Thanks to you and the others that have come back with this. the #type element only existed on one page whereas the script was being run on all pages. I will now move this code to it's own file and only call it on the one page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using HTML right?

after

`$('#type')` returns `undefined`, and then you do `text.replace(/<br>/g, '_');`

you cannot do `undefined.replace`, so it fails, and the execution stops.

Try to add the html code for that JS code

Also, you must add JQuery to your fiddle, in the Frameworks & Extensions part.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9748L/

Answer (score 1):

I just debugged it and it looks like that text is undefined,
so maybe you haven't created the element in html.

```
var text = text.replace(/<br>/g, '_');
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are missing some html code and the text you try to manipulate is `undefined`.
You could add the following html code,

```
<span id="type">is this what you try to do????</span><span id="cursor">_</span>
```

to achieve the effect you are aiming for.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKp5z/